# Subclassing UIView and adding a property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, subclass, objective-c-category

I've tried subclassing the UIView. Because I want an enum in my UIView so I can check if the UIView need to be tapped twice in my game. But I have not so much experience with subclassing. And it is not working. Or do I need to create a category?

The things I did:

- Make subclass UIView
- Create property inside custom subclass
- Change the class from UIView to the subclass in the storyboard
- Change all UIView declarations from my Game Class to the subclass declaration

Code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, viewStaat) {
    ENUMEnkelTap,
    ENUMDubbelTap
};

@interface BannerView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, assign) viewStaat staatVanDeView;

@end
```

And declare the property in the init from UIView.

```
@synthesize staatVanDeView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        staatVanDeView = ENUMDubbelTap;
        NSLog(@"Set");
    }
    return self;
}
```

The Log is not getting called, so I don't know what's wrong. The integer from the `staatVanDeView` stays 0 all the time.

Comment: Nonatomic is just fine as integer is a primitive type; you don't need the assign. If you synthesize the property in your method file then you can get/set the property anywhere you like.

Comment: I've edited it. I cannot set the property apparently and the Log is not getting called.

Comment: Do you upload your view from nib or create it in the code?

Comment: As it's a manually-synthesized property, you need to call `self.staatVanDeView = ENUMDubbelTap`

Comment: @VladislavKovalyov My views are set in the Storyboard, and I've changed the class from the UIViews to my subclass of UIView.

Comment: @Luke It does not work. Still stays at 0 for my integer as it should be 1 from my enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `-initWithFrame:` will not be called when instantiating a view from the storyboard. Use `-initWithCoder:` instead:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
         staatVanDeView = ENUMDubbelTap;
    }
    return self;
}
```

And you won't need the line

```
@synthesize staatVanDeView;
```

because getters and setters for properties are created automatically in recent iOS versions.

Comment: Thanks man this works! Can I remove the `initWithFrame`from my subclass?

Comment: Yes. When you always instantiate your view from the storyboard you can remove the `-initWithFrame` method.